# How can use LEFT JOIN at Sequelize with conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelize.js

#### Relations:

```
import {Topics, Users} from './model-sequelize';
Users.hasMany(Topics, {foreignKey : 'UserID'});
Topics.hasOne(Users, {foreignKey : 'UserID'});

getAllTopics (params, cb) {
    const {PageIndex, PageSize} = params;
    const pg = paging(PageIndex, PageSize)
    Topics.findAll({
        offset: pg.offset,
        limit: pg.limit,
        attributes: {
            exclude: ['IsDelete']
        },
        include:[
            {
                model:Users,
                attributes: ['UserName', 'UserID'],
                required:false
            }
        ],
        where: {
            IsDelete: 0
        },
        order: [[Sequelize.col('LastReplyTime'), 'DESC']]
    }).then(res => {
        cb(null, res)
    }).catch(err => {
        cb(err)
    })
}
```

#### SQL is :

```
SELECT `topics`.`TopicReplies`, 
       `topics`.`TopicHits`, 
       `topics`.`TopicName`, 
       `topics`.`TopicLabel`, 
       `topics`.`LastReplyUserId`, 
       `topics`.`LastReplyTime`, 
       `topics`.`UserID`, 
       `topics`.`TopicContent`, 
       `topics`.`Plate`, 
       `topics`.`ID`, 
       `topics`.`createdAt`, 
       `topics`.`updatedAt`, 
       `user`.`ID` AS `user.ID`, 
       `user`.`UserName` AS `user.UserName`, 
       `user`.`UserID` AS `user.UserID` 
FROM `topics` AS `topics` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` AS `user` ON `topics`.`ID` = `user`.`UserID` 
WHERE `topics`.`IsDelete` = 0 
ORDER BY `LastReplyTime` DESC LIMIT 20, 10;
```

[image]

Conditions is `topics`.`ID` = `user`.`UserID`

#### Question

I want using " ON `topics`.`UserID` = `user`.`UserID` ?

And now the result does not have data for the users table. What can I do ?

Comment: What is your expected result ?

Comment: What you want to do? can you explain about your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have issue with **association** :

Change this:

```
Topics.hasOne(Users, {foreignKey : 'UserID'});
```

To :

```
Topics.belongsTo(Users, {foreignKey : 'UserID'});
```

And try again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it your way, results still the same. join conditions is : ON `topics`.`UserID` = `user`.`ID`

Comment: So what do you need?

Comment: i need conditions is topics.UserID = users.UserID , Join Condition is not primaryKey but UserID .

Comment: @Vito , then you need to change the primary key id to userId in your user table. and that is not proper way of doing , it should be like as suggested in my answer, `topics.UserID = user.ID` is how it should be

Comment: this method should work, i am sorry I don't think it's a good idea to change the primary key